# swf animation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, flash

I have a swf animation that I will like to use in a wpf application. I know I can use a webBrowser control but that control has a white background. As a result if I place that animation on top of an image for instance the white background appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how complex your SWF is but you could try out [this](http://www.mikeswanson.com/swf2xaml/) SWF to WPF converter.  Based on the samples it appears to work quite well and it would allow you to circumvent the need to use a `WebBrowser` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the `WebBrowser` control is essentially your only option. I doubt you'll be able to use it to achieve your desired result, though, since the `WebBrowser` control is actually a Winforms control that's being hosted on the GDI layer, so WPF effects (transparency, for example) won't be available.